# How to transform Flow<List<Flow<T>>> to Flow<List<T>>

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a database query that returns the list of **indexes of objects** for a certain day, i.e.:

```kotlin
getIndexesOfDay(day: Day): Flow<List<String>>
```

Now, I need to listen for **details for each index**, for instance:

```kotlin
getDetailsByIndex(index: String): Flow<Details>
```

So the question is: how can I accomplish this using Flows?

Two important constraints:

1. Changes on the indexes should propagate to the final flow;
2. Changes on any `Details` object should also update the flow.

**What I have already tried:**

```kotlin
getIndexesOfDay(todayDay)
          .map { indexes ->
              indexes?.map {
                      mIndex->
                  getDetailsByIndex(mIndex)
              }
          }
```

But it returns a `Flow<List<Flow<Details>>>` instead of the desired `Flow<List<Details>>`

*Appreciate any help!*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I believe it should be possible using [flatMapLatest()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-latest.html) and [combine()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html):

```kotlin
getIndexesOfDay(todayDay)
    .flatMapLatest { indexes ->
        combine(indexes.map { getDetailsByIndex(it) }) { it.asList() }
    }
```

For each new list of indexes, it invokes `getDetailsByIndex()` multiple times to acquire a list of flows and then combines these flows into a single flow of details lists.

The drawback is that whenever indexes change, it throws away all `Flow<Details>` objects, even if an index existed in both old and new list of indexes. It would be probably better to create some kind of a cache of detail flows per each index.

Comment: I think `asList()` is acceptable here. The docs for `combine` have no warning about leaking out the Array, and the source code shows they take care not to reuse Array instances.

Comment: Thanks, updated @Tenfour04

Answer (score 0):

Hi I loved the @broot solution.

But I have an issue with the Data base empty case.
It is loading forever. :(

After reading
https://medium.com/digigeek/from-zero-to-hero-series-kotlin-sequences-channels-flows-part-3-flows-5cdb391295b8

I decided to write some code:

```
override suspend fun getProductModels() : Flow<List<ProductModel>> {
         return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
             return@withContext productDAO.getProductEntities().flatMapLatest {
                     productEntities: List<ProductWithElements> ->
                 
                 if(productEntities.isEmpty()) {
                     val productModelListFlow : Flow<List<ProductModel>> =  flow {
                             emit(emptyList())
                     }
                     return@flatMapLatest productModelListFlow 
                 }
                 val productModelFlowList : List<Flow<ProductModel>> = productEntities.map { 
                         productEntity: ProductWithElements ->
                     photoDAO.getPhotoEntities(productEntity.product.productId).map {
                         productEntity.toModel(it)
                     }
                 }
                 
                 //combine Returns a Flow
                 // whose values are generated with transform function
                 // by combining the most recently emitted values by each flow.
                 val productModelListFlow : Flow<List<ProductModel>> = combine(productModelFlowList){
                         arrayOfProductModels: Array<ProductModel> ->
                     arrayOfProductModels.asList()
                 }
                 return@flatMapLatest productModelListFlow
             }
         }
     }
```

I change the flatMapLastest with FlatmapConcat to wait the completition of the inner flow.

Edit: I change the FlatmapConcat with flatMapLastest to auto update the screen of my composables.

Thanks.

Happy Hacking !